# Importing Bootstrap classes in Angular SCSS file grossly increases file size

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, ng-bootstrap

In my application (Angular 16, Bootstrap 5.3, ngBootstrap 15.1), in an attempt to use semantic class names in a component, I've set up the following SCSS file:

```
@use "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid";

.my-table {
  .headline,
  .headline-left,
  .headline-center,
  .headline-right,
  .footline,
  .footline-left,
  .footline-center,
  .footline-right {
    @extend .d-flex;
    @extend .justify-content-between;
    @extend .align-items-center;
    @extend .my-1;
  }
}
```

When the application builds, this increases the size of main.js by around 250K, about 10%. I'd thought the transpiler would pull out exactly what it needed but this makes it look like the entire bootstrap-grid file is making it into the deployed output. Is there a better way to do this, one that doesn't take up so much space?

I realize in this case I can just go in and use CSS grid styling directly (**update:** and I just did), but even so I want to know if there's a better way to do this, such as if I want to associate semantic class names with particular Bootstrap colors.

Comment: It seems you're using `bootstrap-grid.scss`. I haven't tried that before, but I'm using `grid.scss` instead. [Link](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/grid/src/component/grid.component.scss) This gives me a prod bundle of 2.34 kB

Comment: I've seen references to grid.scss in other places but I don't have it. In my node_modules/bootstrap, no files have a name beginning with "grid". There's bootstrap/scss/_grid.scss  and bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss. That's it. But then, when I tried importing one of those, the transpiler (or whatever) said it couldn't find it.